# confirmation yes or no message in asp net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a problem to show confirm yes or no message box in asp.net.

```
string script = "alert(\"Insert success !!! \");";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "key", script, true);
```

I can display message box insert success but i dont know how to make confirm message box.
this message box,

```
if choose yes
{
do something
}
else
{
do something
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a confirm box in JavaScript by using: `confirm()`.

You need to implement this code in your ASP.NET code.

```js
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
  alert("OK");
} else {
  alert("BAD");
}
```

Try with this script:

```
string script = "if(confirm(\"Are you sure?\")){ alert(\"OK\");} else { alert(\"BAD\");}";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "key", script, true);
```

Comment: @OP This is ENTIRELY client side. You need to pair this kind of code with AJAX calls to let the server know.

Comment: According on how the question was performed, the OP is asking about .NET embedded JavaScript code.
My answer is intended to provide a guide for the OP have a starting point for him to implement the code.

Comment: It's a good starting point but i've just met a lot of starting/aspiring developers puzzled because the server does nothing in these kinds of scenarios so i'd rather spell the caveat out early.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I just put this code in my ASP.Net but the confirm and alrert is error:does not exist in the current context. Sorry, Im newbie in ASP.NET

Comment: @HenzD'Wraith I've updated my answer, please check. Let me know if this works.