# Using MessageBox C# - Throws Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use MessageBox in C#

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

MessageBox.Show("Some text", "Some title",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Still I got this error. How to fix it?

```
The MessageBox does not exist in current context.
```

Comment: You are trying to use in asp.net, webforms? it could not be used there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MessageBox in C# showing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741954/messagebox-in-c-sharp-showing-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.net doesn't support MessageBox..
You can use this instead of MessageBox.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('" + Your Message here + "');", true);
```

to use this:

```
String str = "This is your message.";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('" + str  + "');", true);
```

This way:

```
private void show(string message)
{
    System.Web.UI.Page page = this.Page;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "popup", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

To use this:

```
 show("this is your message");
```

Comment: I used this line. but "this" syntax throws error. What word should I replace to it?

Comment: Throws the same error. I put the codes at may method, XXXXX.aspx.cs. Is there any conflict?

Comment: no problem about that.. what error? do you have this above? using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

Comment: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

Comment: You are using static procedure i think. You can try it in form_load first to test if working.

Comment: I tried in page load. it works, but how can i use it inside methods? Iam using this to show or test what is my variable's value.

Comment: Still i can't use it inside statics methods.

Comment: change  From "private void show(string message)"  To   "private  static void show(string message)"

Comment: Then, I got error in 'this' at show(), it says that 'this' is not valid in a static property.

Answer (score 5):

You can not use `MessageBox` within `asp.net`, try using `Javascript` confirm instead.
Here is its usage 
[confirmation yes or no message in asp net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234574/confirmation-yes-or-no-message-in-asp-net) or you can use it for some other problems too.